# OPAM package not running

Tags: ocaml, opam

I've installed OPAM and run the initialization and updated my .bashrc code too. I then installed the ocamlfind package, which went successfully. But when I try

```
#use "topfind";;
```

I get the following

```
Cannot find file topfind
```

I'm running ocaml 4.00.1 built from source on Opensuse 12.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `$OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH` is not defined, you have to defined it:

```
export OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH=/home/%user%/.opam/%version%/lib/toplevel
```

Don't forget to change `%user%` and your compiler `%version%`

Check this [issue](https://github.com/OCamlPro/opam-repository/issues/34) on the opam bugtracker.

Comment: Hi, there is no version directory in the ".opam" directory. There are only `aliases`  `archives`  `compilers`  `config`  `descr` and others like that.

Comment: I added a small modification, the path was `/home/%user%/.opam/system/lib/toplevel` and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

First, you need to export the right environment variables by doing:

```
eval `opam config env`
```

To be more effective, you should put that line in your `~/.profile` (or `~/.bashrc`).

Then, if you are using the system compiler, you can add these lines to your `~/.ocamlinit`:

```
let () =
  try Topdirs.dir_directory (Sys.getenv "OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH")
  with Not_found -> ()
```

We are working on improving this process before releasing 1.0.

Comment: This worked too. Thanks for OPAM, I never could get GODI running before and installing libraries used to be a pain, now it's a cinch!

Answer (score 1):

What if you start toplevel as

`rlwrap ocaml -I "$OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH"`

You can also try alternative toplevel: `utop` (it exists in OPAM)

Comment: Hi, I don't have rlwrap installed, and i've setup Emacs with the default ocaml interpreter, so I don't want to keep switching to "utop" in tuareg. Thanks anyway.

Comment: `rlwrap` is not needed. `ocaml -I "$OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH"` should fix the problem imho.

Comment: Once I set the `$OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH` variable, I could run just `ocaml` itself.